# Not able to expose a web service properly in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, jersey

This is the part of my pom.xml which shows the build :

```
<build>
        <finalName>services</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Enabling and configuring web resources filtering -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>web.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

My Web.xml looks like this :

```
   <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

        <display-name>services</display-name>


        <!-- location of spring xml files. Context-param helps you store the param name and value globally -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- the listener that kick-starts Spring -->
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Rest service</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.application.newsfeed.svc</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        </servlet>
        <!--  URL patterns  -->
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Rest service</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

My applicationContext.xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
                <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System" />
                <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties" />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <!-- The new Properties -->
            <util:properties>
                <prop key="jsse.enableSNIExtension">false</prop>
            </util:properties>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="userValidation" class = "com.application.newsfeed.dao.impl.ReqValidationDaoImpl" />

    <bean id="newsfeed" class = "com.application.newsfeed.business.impl.newsfeedBusiness" />

    <bean id = "transform" class = "com.application.newsfeed.response.impl.transformResponsetoJSON" />

    <bean id = "getNewsfeeddao" class = "com.application.newsfeed.dao.impl.getNewsfeedDaoImpl" />

    <bean id = "getNewsfeed" class = "com.application.newsfeed.svc.getNewsfeed" />

    <bean id="appDataSource" class = "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="sdds" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="appJdbcTemplate" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref = "appDataSource"> </constructor-arg>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

And In the package com.application.newsfeed.svc , I have a class getNewsfeed:

```
@Service
@Path("/newsfeed/{username}")
public class getNewsfeed {

    @Autowired
    private ItransformResponsetoJSON transform;

    @Autowired
    private InewsfeedBusiness newsfeed;

    @GET
    public Response getNewsfeed(@PathParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("page") int page) {

        GetNewsfeedRequestParam requestParams = null;

         Response response = null;


        try{
            requestParams = new GetNewsfeedRequestParam(username,page);
            new GetNewsfeedRequestValidator().validateRequest();
            List<Newsfeed> newsfeedResponse = newsfeed.getNewsfeed(requestParams);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

When I run the application on server, this is my console log :

```
Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
        WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:app' did not find a matching property.
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Server built:          Dec 7 2015 13:07:11 UTC
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Server number:         7.0.67.0
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: OS Version:            10.10.5
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_71-b15
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/pgoel/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/pgoel/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.67
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/pgoel/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/pgoel/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.67
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/pgoel/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/pgoel/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/endorsed
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
        INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
        INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/pgoel/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
        INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
        INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
        INFO: Initialization processed in 471 ms
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
        INFO: Starting service Catalina
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
        INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
        INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
        INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
        INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
        INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
        INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Apr 12 10:43:51 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
        INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
        INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3af05cbe: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean#0,userValidation,newsfeed,transform,getNewsfeeddao,getNewsfeed,curofyDataSource,curofyJdbcTemplate]; root of factory hierarchy
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
        INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 300 ms
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
        INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
          com.application.newsfeed.svc
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
        INFO: Root resource classes found:
          class com.application.newsfeed.svc.getNewsfeed
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
        INFO: No provider classes found.
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet getContext
        INFO: Using default applicationContext
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
        INFO: Registering Spring bean, getNewsfeed, of type com.application.newsfeed.svc.getNewsfeed as a root resource class
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:51 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
        INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 03:31 PM'
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
        INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
        INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
        Apr 12, 2016 10:43:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
        INFO: Server startup in 1473 ms
```

Now when I hit the url :

```
http://localhost:8080/services/newsfeed/pgoel2?page=1
```

I get `404`. Can somebody please help me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Best guess is eclipse does not deploy your app with the name you think. What do you see when you list the context in eclipse server configuration? or when you list the files in `/Users/pgoel/Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps`

Comment: Yes this was the error. But is there any reason so as to why this is not happening? I have properly mentioned my build. Also the war created is also services.war